# Configured product appears to be out of stock while it is not in Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, migration, stock-status

I have issue after migration Prestashop to Magento2. All Products details are migrate but Some of Configured products are show out of stock but in backend it's in stock.

Magento Version: 2.0.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the child products associated with that configurable products? If they're either

1. 0 in inventory
2. "Status" is disabled
3. "Product Online" is "Off"

Then the child product will not show on configurable product page . If NONE of the child products are available, the configurable product will not show.